# 03 civic si hatchback

Tags: honda, electrical, starting, civic

I just Recently put a new motor and started it drove it home. Woke up the next day to go somewhere go to start my car and nothing no power. I have a breathalyzer in my car due to dui, I can’t even get that to turn on the battery is fine new battery charged I tried jumping it nothing alternator is fine, but as I started to realize every time I hit the brakes and clutch to turn the car on I lose all power what is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you have a very poor power connection. Check the main leads at both ends to make sure they are tight. Any higher amperage load can cause you to drop power in a situation like this.

Comment: Did all the ground cables get reinstalled and tightened on the engine? Did the starter battery cable get tightened, double check the work.

Comment: I did actually just the ground an tighten them up I got it started now I thing the tps is acting up